# For para incrementação no Python

Tags: python, loop, for

Eu aprendi que, no `Python`, para fazer um *loop* com `for`, de 1 a 10, utilizamos o `range`.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i)
```

Geralmente, em outras linguagens, quando requeremos fazer uma incrementação simples, utilizamos o bom e velho `i++`.

Exemplo em JavaScript:

```
for (var i; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Eu tenho alguns dúvidas em relação a essa iteração:

1. Com eu faria para ao invés de incrementar eu decrementar?
2. Como eu faria para **incrementar** esse *loop* de **dois em dois** valores, partindo de **1**?
3. Existe alguma maneira de fazer um *loop*, como geralmente se faz em outras linguagens, como o `i++`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O `for` do Python na verdade é um `for each`. Não existe um `for` tradicional com três elementos onde você coloca o início, fim e passo de "incremento". Mas se pensar bem este for tradicional é apenas *syntax sugar*. Um `while` faz a mesma coisa.

```
i = 1 #inicializador
while i < 10: #verifica a condição
    print(i) #o corpo, a ação
    i += 2 #o passo de "incremento"
```

Decrementar:

```
i = 10 #inicializador
while i > 0: #verifica a condição
    print(i) #o corpo, a ação
    i -= 1 #o passo de "incremento"
```

É simples assim.

Existe uma diferença de usar um `continue` já que ormalmente em um `for` tradicional um `continue` não pulará o passo "incremento", nesta construção do `while` ele pulará, então é preciso mais cuidado.

Mas este não é o jeito mais "pitônico". O uso do `range` é sempre recomendado conforme mostra a resposta do Orion. Veja o incremento de 2:

```
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    print(i)
```

Decrementando:

```
for i in range(10, 1, -1):
    print(i)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3HM0x1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Loops). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Loops.py).

Intuitivamente o `while` deveria ser mais rápido mas como o `range` é escrito em mais baixo nível ele consegue produzir um código mais otimizado.

Comment: A forma com while não é mais rápida não - estmaos aocstumados a pensar em C em que um "range" seria uma chamada de função, com muitas intruções nativas, e `i+=1` seria uma única instrução - mas em Python `i+=1` tambem envolve chamada de métodos, maniulação de constantes, etc...

Comment: para um loop com 100000 interações, em python2 com range: 3.06ms por interação, com while e `i+=1`: 8.41ms por interação. Python3.3 com range ficou um pouco mais lento: 3.58ms,mas muito mais rápido que o while ainda.

Comment: @jsbueno faz algum sentido. Na verdade é um absurdo que isto ocorra, mas essas linguagens tem dessas coisas. Mas o que vale é medir mesmo.

Comment: Não, não é um absurdo: a linguagem tem uma camada de abstração para você se preocupar com o seu problema, não como o computador funciona . Essa é a ideía de usar uma lignuagem de muito alto nível como Python.- a gente nem percebe que fica viciado em pensar primeiro como o computador funciona lá por dentro - mas a abstração no caso é o builtin Range que retorna um iterador - usado em "for" no Python só na pequena porcentagem de casos em que alguém queira de fato um número e nao percorrer uma sequência de items (linash de um arquivo de log, caractéres de uma string, chaves de dicionário)

Comment: Depis que o problema está resolvido algoritmicamente, se precisar otimizar, você vai atras disso, usando profilers, e re-escrevendo as partes críticas em algo que use código nativo.

Comment: @jsbueno até seria legal um debate sobre isto. O que você diz faz sentido mas ainda acho um absurdo que seja assim :) De qualquer mudei a resposta porque parece que não bastou eu dizer que o certo era fazer como na respostado Orion, então coloquei o código certo para agradar os pitonistas que querm ver o "jeito certo".

Comment: Gostei bastante da cara que o texto ficou agora - "intuitivamente o while deveria ser mais rápido..." ficou legal.

Comment: Estou tentando usar `range(1, 10, -1)`, porém não está funcionando

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi ato falho, se vai decrementar tem que começar do maior :)

Comment: Deixa eu dar uma moral para a resposta do @Orion então.

Answer (score 9):

Para decrementar:

```
for i in range(10, 1, -1):
    print i
```

Para incrementar de dois em dois:

```
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    print i
```

Para fazer `i++` não tem como, teria que usar `contador+=1`

Answer (score 6):

Como o pessoal colocou nas outras respostas, o que acontece é que o `for` nas linguagens que herdaram a sintaxe do C é apenas um `while` incrementado.

Em Python é raro na verdade usarmos um `for` numérico em uma aplicação - por que na grande maioria dos casos, num `for` o que queremos é efetuar um conjunto de operações para cada elemento de uma sequência. A sequência pode ser elementos de um vetor, linhas de um arquivo, registros recuperados de um banco de dados, letras de uma string ... 
Em outras linguagens, em geral as pessoas fazem um `for` com a variável indo de 0 até o comprimento da sequência, e num dos primeiros comandos dentro do `for` fazem uma atribuição do tipo `item = sequencia[i]`. 
Em Python, o `for` que existe desde que a linguagem foi criada na década de 90 é o que é as vezes chamado de `for each` em outras linguagens (mas não em Javascript, ali o for each não é muito consistente).

Nos casos em que queiramos realmente contar números, em Python há a chamada `range` que retorna um objeto bem flexível para contagem de números inteiros, sendo trivial passar parâmetros para contagens decrescentes ou de 2 em 2. Como é o que você está perguntando, é melhor deixar claro. For de 10 até 1, decrescente: `for i in range(10, 0, -1)`: o 10 é o parâmetro inicial, 0, o final: quando o valor for esse a interação para, e -1 o incremento. Da mesma forma, de 2 em 2: `for i in range(1, 10, 2):` aqui a contagem começa em 0, e aumenta de 2 em 2, e para quando o valor for 10 ou maior.

O mais frequente é precisarmos ao mesmo tempo de um item de uma sequência e de seu número de índice. Por exemplo, se queremos comparar cada letra de uma string com a próxima, para saber se são iguais:

```
palavra = input("Digite uma palavra: ")
total_repetidas = 0
for i, letra in enumerate(palavra):
   if i < len(palavra) - 1 and letra == palavra[i + 1]:
       total_repetidas += 1
print(f"Há um total de {total_repetidas} letras iguais em sequência em {palavra}")
```

Aqui, a chamada "enumerate" vai retornar, para cada elemento na sequencia contida em `palavra` uma tupla com dois elementos: o primeiro sendo a posição do próximo elemento, e o segundo o elemento em si. Uma outra característica do Python permite que se coloque duas variáveis separadas por `,` no `for`,e o conteúdo da tupla é associado, respectivamente cada item para uma variável.

Agora isso nem é o mais legal. O mais legal é que é facílimo criar suas próprias chamadas que podem ser usadas em um  `for`, da mesma forma que o `range` e o `enumerate`. Basta que a função tenha a expressão `yield` dentro: o yield funciona como se fosse um `return` parcial: a função retorna um valor, que pode ser usado num `for` (ou de outras formas); quando o for e executado de novo, a função continua rodando de onde estava - e no próximo `yield` cria o próximo valor.   esse tipo de função se torna uma "função geradora".

Com isso, as vezes código que não é a finalidade da nossa aplicação principal pode ser escrito num lugar separado - podendo ser testado de forma independente. Vamos supor que eu queira fazer um `for` que vá gerando os quadrados dos números em vez de um incremento linear:

```
def quadrados(n):
   for i in range(n):
      yield n * n
```

Pronto - só isso. Se quero agora imprimir todos os quadrados dos números de 0 até 100 posso fazer:

```
for i in quadrados(100):
    print(i)
```

(como na chamada de funções normais, as variáveis dentro de `quadrados` são isoladas - por isso posso re-utilizar a variável `i` sem qualquer perigo).

Se eu quiser uma função que retorne a série de fibonacci  até que o valor da série ultrapasse um número x:

```
def fibonacci(max_):
   a = 1
   b = 1
   while a < max_:
      yield a
      c = b
      b += a
      a = c
```

(De novo, com a história da atribuição de múltiplas variáveis usando uma "," em Python é possível re-escrever as três últimas linhas assim:

```
b, a = b + a, b
```

como funciona isso: primeiro o Python executa a expressão do lado direito. Como tem uma ",", ele vai criar uma tupla. Então ele executa a expressão no primeiro elemento da tupla `a + b` e o segundo elemento -  e esses são os valores da tupla temporária: (a + b, b). Em seguida, o primeiro elemento dessa tupla vai pra variável "b" e o segundo para a variável "a" )